# Phonegap Android Build Does Not Connect to Other Servers

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

When I make an android build with phonegap, download it on my phone and launch it, it wont make the webservice calls. In fact it wont retrieve the JQuery files from the cdn link that I have in the header. I downloaded JQuery and placed an internal link thinking I might make some progress, but although jquery now works the web service calls don't work. I have read plenty of articles and done several things. Maybe is something stupid and small that I am overlooking, but I have tried...

-Editing my config.xml file by adding

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<allow-intent href="itms:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

-Editing my index.html's header by adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *  'unsafe-inline'; script-src *  'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

I make calls to the server like so

```
$.post( "http://mobile.lbtelematics.com/appCalls.php", {type: "check"}, function(data){verify(data)}, "text").fail(function(){alert("Server busy or down. Please try again later...")});
```

Every time I open the app I get the fail alert. If some guidance can be given that would be great. I can typically solve these things after sometime, but I've been busting my head for the past two days over this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing a chrome://inspect on the app might be useful to see your console messages and responses.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try taking your Content-Security-Policy meta tag which you have as:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *  'unsafe-inline'; script-src *  'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And adding in:

```
'unsafe-eval'
```

to make JQuery work properly.  So try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *  'unsafe-inline'; script-src *  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *">
```

You definitely want to stick with bundling JQuery in your app and only getting data / support files from your server at runtime, not JavaScript frameworks and libraries that the app needs to work - put those in your www somewhere in your Cordova app and ship them inside the app.